# W/System (11471): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

When I put my data it shows me this code so how can I solve it
[image]

```
W/System  (11471): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the emulator is connected to the internet.
Sometimes the wifi is on but doesn't connect to the internet. This is how I fixed it anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).